# Graph API tells me an object doesn't exist while it does

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting to create a little app to get the names associated with Facebook IDs for a bigger project. I just started to use the Facebook API and it's giving me weird results. Most of the time, everything works fine. I use this code (I'm using Python, but that doesn't really matter here since it's the Facebook API that is causing the problem) :

```
def downloadString(url, params):
    cookie = {}
    data = requests.get(url,cookies=cookie,params=params)
    return data.text
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/"  
id = "afriendidhere"
dl = basics.downloadString(url + id, {"access_token":accesstoken})
res = json.loads(dl)
```

As I said, most of the time, it works just fine, giving me the name of the given person. Though, for two people in my friends list, I get the following message :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'theid' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "FTfrh78XjW/"
  }
}
```

I don't understand why. The person with this id does exist, since I can access the page http://facebook.com/messages/theid and it's giving me my conversation history with this user. It's always the same people who cause the error, everyone else works perfecty.

Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Is the ID a page or a user?

Comment: It's a user who's friend on Facebook with me.

Comment: Is the friend using your app?

Comment: see my answer. how did you even get the IDs?

Comment: No, the friend is not using the app. I got the IDs by parsing my messenger.com page.

Comment: that´s scraping, which is not allowed. you MUST work with the app scoped user ids you get after authorizing users.

Comment: _"Graph API tells me an object doesn't exist while it does"_ - no, it doesn't. You are ignoring half of what that message is saying.

Answer (score 3):

You are only supposed to get data from users who authorized your App. Authorized them, get their App Scoped ID and name with the `/me` endpoint. More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user

Comment: But why can I get the other names then ?

Comment: maybe they deactivated the app platforms, in that case no app can get any details. either way, you got the ids in a wrong way, see my other comments. authorize users and it will work with their app scoped user ID. you actually don´t even need their ID, just use /me to get their name.

Comment: I can get their name through /me ? How ? I mean without having them to allow the app ? Because I can't ask each friend to allow the app it would be ridiculous

Comment: well, that is the only way to get access to their data: they have to authorize your app. please read the first sentence of my answer, it´s the most important information.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to publish the page in settings

Page Visibility --> Publish

Save changes

Comment: Not working this solution Please suggest some thing new

Answer (score 0):

Try removing any visibility limitations from your Page's settings (such as country restrictions etc)